# Odd behaviour of XeLaTeX under Linux

Tags: xetex, luatex, linux

I am experimenting with LaTeX under Linux (my setup: Miktex + TeXStudio + Ubuntu-based distro).
I am encountering very odd behaviour when I am trying to compile my `.tex` files with XeLaTeX (LuaLaTeX works perfectly fine).
Here are some code snippets and errors that `XeLaTeX` produced:

1. **example #1**

> ```
> \documentclass[a4]{report}
> \usepackage{fontspec,lipsum}
> \setmainfont{Cyklop}
> \begin{document}
> \lipsum[1]
> \textit{\lipsum[2]}
> \end{document}
> ```

Errors:
[image]
[image]

2. **example #2**

> ```
> \documentclass[oneside,a4paper,10pt]{report}
>     \usepackage{fontspec} 
>     \usepackage{polyglossia}
>     \setdefaultlanguage{english}
>     \usepackage{microtype} 
>     \usepackage{libertine} 
>     \usepackage{vmargin}
>     \setmarginsrb{2cm}{1.5cm}{2cm}{1cm}{0pt}{0mm}{0pt}{13mm}
>     \usepackage{lipsum}
>     \begin{document}
>     \lipsum[1]
>     \textit{\lipsum[2]}
>     \end{document}
> ```

**Errors:**
[image]
[image]
As I have mentioned before, LuaLaTeX doesn't give any errors with exact same code snippets (fond `Cyklop` is installed, indeed). I am very curious what is  wrong with XeLaTeX under Linux and how/if this can be fixed.I have not encountered this behaviour under Windows.

Comment: Does `fc-cache -f -v` on the terminal solve it?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I used this command when adding new fonts on the system.

Comment: xelatex is much more picky regarding font names (and font locations). Check the font name carefully, or try to use the file name instead.